# Something wrong with string to integer conversion

Tags: java

I make chessboard, where alone king will walk according to the rules of chess.
Below it's method to make, it called for 2 times for i and j coordinate of King, I Made input variable String to check if this King's coordinates already exist. Than I try to convert it to integer, seems something wrong with this conversion.

```
import java.util.*;
public class King {
    int move(String iK){
        Random rand = new Random();
        Integer coordinateKing = Integer.valueOf(iK);
        if (iK == null){           
            coordinateKing = rand.nextInt(8);
        }else{
            int caseI;
            switch(caseI = rand.nextInt(2)){
                case 0: if (coordinateKing < 8){ coordinateKing++; } else {caseI = rand.nextInt(2);}
                break;
                case 1: if (coordinateKing > 0){ coordinateKing--; } else {caseI = rand.nextInt(2);}
                break;
                default: 
                break;
            }           
        }       
        return coordinateKing;
    }
}
```

I have problem like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
    at chess_engine.King.move(King.java:6)
    at chess_engine.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the value of `iK` ?

Comment: `iK` is `null` and hence you can't parse it. May you want to just declare `coordinateKing` and move 
        `coordinateKing = Integer.valueOf(iK);` in the else block ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to convert `iK` to an integer before you check to see if it's `null`.  This line is where the exception is thrown:

```
Integer coordinateKing = Integer.valueOf(iK);
```

But you check `if (iK == null)` on the line following that.  You should do a `null` test first.  You can fix this by declaring `coordinateKing` before your `if` statement and setting its value in the `if...else` blocks.

```
Integer coordinateKing = 0;

if (iK == null){           
    coordinateKing = rand.nextInt(8);
} else {
    coordinateKing = Integer.valueOf(iK);
    int caseI;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You call this

```
Integer coordinateKing = Integer.valueOf(iK);
```

but `iK` can be NULL there. do your null check first

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty self-explanatory. iK is a null String, which can't be converted to an Integer. What Integer do you want when iK is null?

Answer (score 1):

It is a runtime error: here the iK is receiving a null value and an Integer object can store null but the method `valueOf()` internally uses the `parseInt()` method which returns an int value and a null cannot be converted to int